# Can Windows in macOS Boot Camp access an external HDD formatted as Journaled extended?

Tags: windows, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I currently have a MacBook Pro with an external HDD formatted as journaled extended and use this for my time machine backups.

I'm planning on adding Windows using Boot Camp but was wondering if Windows will be able to read/write to that same external HDD (just documents, like media files). Or will I need to create a second partition on that external drive for Windows use?

I'm unable to find answers on Google since it's either not Boot Camp related, or they're talking about internal storage, or on the rare few results that I did find something, it's contradictory to each other.

So, anyone out there with macOS, Windows in Boot Camp & an external HDD to help me find the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to install an [HFS+ driver](https://backstage.paragon-software.com/free/hfs-windows-free/) to Windows. The “+” in the FS name is a synonym to your “extended” (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)). However, the driver webpage does not mention “journaled”, although that’s the option used for a macOS drive most commonly. According to my experience in Linux, a journaled HFS+ drive can only be mounted *read-only* using a 3rd party driver (at least that one distributed with Xubuntu). The [journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) is used to track changes to the filesystem, so it can be simply ignored when using the partition as read-only. However, the 3rd party drivers would have to be able to work with it in order to be able to write.

So I would recommend the other way, creating two partitions. You should use FAT32 for the data partition if you want to use it to share data between Windows and macOS. Make sure to use GPT partition map (unless you want to use Windows XP or older), so you can resize the partitions later. I personally have been using such an external disk with two partitions for years without problems.

> I'm unable to find answers on Google since it's either not Boot Camp related

Do not rely on the Boot Camp keyword. Just like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)) mentions, it’s just a tool to install Windows on a Mac. Once Windows has been installed on a Mac, it behaves much like any other Windows.